# How to create static block to display banners in home page in magento 2

Tags: collection, static-block, magento2.2.2, home-page

I have created admin grid and form using ui-component for adding banners.

**In frontend I have displayed the banners collection by hitting the controller path. Without controller path, how do I show my template(phtml) which contains collection of banners in home page?**

**How do I create static block in admin to display my collection(phtml) in homepage.Please provide me a solution.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code in CMS homepage content.

```
{{block class="Magento\Bannerslider\Block\Slideshow" template="Magento_Bannerslider::bannerslider.phtml"}}
```

Replace class and template as per your module.